# How can I setup an application that uses SQL Server 2008 Express on a machine that already has SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, deployment, sql-server-2008-express

I have developed an application in VB.Net (VS2010) and make a setup & deployment that checked in prerequisites `SQL Server 2008 Express`.

When I install it on another system that use installed application that uses SQL Server 2005 Express, I get this error:

> SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) cannot upgrade the existing instance of SQL Server 2005 Express (x64 WoW) named 'SQLEXPRESS'. Uninstall this instance of SQL Server 2005 Express and retry installing SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64)

I think only one SQL Server Express can exist on a machine.

But I can't uninstall SQL Server 2005, because an application uses it.

What can I do in setup to prevent this error?

Thanks

Comment: You can migrate the existing application with a little downtime, or go virtual and have several instances of sql server on different VMs.

Comment: At what point during your install did you receive that error? I managed to install SQL Server 2008 Express on top of SQL Server 2005 Express (86).

Comment: When I double-click on setup!.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily have **multiple instances** of SQL Server - any edition - on a machine at the same time.

The instances must have **unique** names, however.

So if the SQL Server 2005 Express is installed as `SQLEXPRESS`, then your SQL Server 2008 Express must be installed with a **different instance name**, e.g. `SQLX2008` or whatever - just not `SQLEXPRESS`

And your application's config file of course must be updated to connect to that new, separate instance by its name.

Comment: In which way Can I rename my sql server 2008 Express?

Comment: @student: you just need to choose a different instance name when installing

Comment: @marc_c:In my machine, I have installed the sql server by installing the vs2010.Can I install a new instance of sql express 2008 by vs2010? or must download it from microsoft and then install it?

Comment: @student: I would download it from [Microsoft's web site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695)

Comment: @marc_c:I download Sql Express 2008 And install it with new instance name.Can you Introduce reference to modify and update application's config? Thanks.